RN android WorkManager-HeadlessJSTaskService wont work when app is closed
I'm currently working on a React Native sample app and I want to implement periodic synchronization using WorkManager and Headless JS task. The Work manager is responsible for the periodic wake ups, ad to init the headless task. the Task in JS side is responsible for the actual sync.
I need to start a headless task when the app is closed, but it fails due to background service restrictions.
However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to start the headless task from the WorkManager, while app is closed (not happening while app is minimised to background). Specifically, I'm receiving the following error:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.testapp75/.MyHeadlessJsService (has extras) }: app is in background uid ...

sharing some code samples
index.js
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () =>
  require('./SomeTaskName'),
);

MyHeadlessJsService
    override fun getTaskConfig(intent: Intent?): HeadlessJsTaskConfig? {
        Log.d("BBB", "getTaskConfig: ")
        val data: WritableMap = Arguments.createMap()
        data.putString("key", "value0857")
        return HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "SomeTaskName", // The name of the task as registered in JavaScript
            data, // Input data to the task (optional)
            500, // Timeout for the task
            true // Whether the task requires the device to be awake
        )
    }

MyWorker
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val service = Intent(
            applicationContext,
            MyHeadlessJsService::class.java
        )
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("foo", "bar")
        service.putExtras(bundle)
        applicationContext.startService(service)
        return Result.success()
    }

AndroidManifest
        <service android:name=".MyHeadlessJsService" />


Note: please do not suggest to start foreground service.
Questions:
Is there a recommended approach to initiate a headless task from WorkManager in this scenario?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I tried different variations of the service declaration in JS, and create a sample app to simplify things.
